# Indefinite integral of a constant

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int k \,\mathrm{d}x = k+c $$

Why is it that the upon integral is equal to $k+c$? Shouldn't it be $kx+c$? Since it's a constant. When you integrate constants you get $ax$ or $kx$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  You may want to see [the MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've chnaged the title so that it summarises better the question.

Comment: Only if $k=ae^x$ where a is constant

Comment: Where are you seeing this integration?  Are you sure that you have copied it down correctly?  Is there additional context to the problem which might indicate that $k$ is an exponential function?

Answer (score 3):

The integral calculates an expression that when it gets differentiated, it gives you the expression that was inside the integral. This means that :

$$\int kdx=kx+c$$

if $k \space \text{constant} \space \in \mathbb R$.

Double checking by what I mentioned above :

$$(kx+c)'=(kx)' + c' = k$$

which yields you the initial expression.